# Case sharing rule only applying to cases without an AccountId?

Tags: case, permissions, sharing

I'm trying to create a case that can be hidden from standard users (firings, commission questions, etc.). I was able to do this in my partial sandbox but cannot get it working in production.

I've got the issue narrowed down. I can only hide cases that don't have an Account associated.

[According to Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_rule_considerations.htm):

> Regardless of sharing rules, users can, at a minimum, view the accounts in their territories. Also, users can be granted access to view and edit the contacts, opportunities, and cases associated with their territories’ accounts.

I assume this is because of the rule above? We do not have Salesforce Territory Management enabled. So I assume I'm stuck figuring out how to remove the AccountID from certain cases?

Comment: So, in production you have those cases and associated with Account? and you want to de-asscoiate accountId of that type of cases, right?

Comment: @SantanuBoral Yeah, but it's not letting me clear out the account. If edit and clear the field, it goes back to the previous value when I save.

Comment: it shouldn't be case-to-Account is lookup relationship. I think case is related to contact and from contact, it taking the account. Can you remove the contact and account both and check the result, I think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to territory.

The Account is populated to the Case via selected Contact. So, if case has contact then associated Account related to Contact will be saved to Case record.

Only removing the Account and saving the Case will not solve the issue. As, account will again be re-associated via contact lookup record.

> Finally, remove **both** the Contact lookup and Account lookup values and save the case record. **This way, case will be disassociated from Account**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at your account sharing rules.

Sharing rules on account allow you to specify not only the access level for accounts, but also specify the access level on opportunities, contacts, and cases.

To make cases private, you dont need to blank out the account on the case, you just need to ensure that your account sharing rules dont give access to cases by setting case access to private on all account sharing rules.

See step 10 [on this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_rules_create_account.htm&type=0)

> In the remaining fields, select the access settings for the records associated with the shared accounts.

If you have a business need that requires account sharing rules to give access to cases, then it gets more challenging, as account level rules dont let you determine which types of cases to share.  Not sure what the best option is in that case, but perhaps some crafty usage of case team would be an option.

Comment: Santanu solved my immediate problem, but I do need to look into this as a long term fix. Unfortunately I really only admin Service Cloud so it's something I need to discuss with the person that admins the sales side. Still very useful. Thanks!